# cURL в Node.js и параметры

Tags: php, node.js

Здраствуйте ребята. Вопрос такой, хочу сделать POST-запрос в node.js через http.request(). В php нет проблемм, авторизацию прохожу. Но не знаю как передать php вариант `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` и `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`в node.js.

PHP Koд:

```
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HEADER,false);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$this->cookiefile);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$this->cookiefile);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
```

А тут параметры в Node.js (предыдущий код хочу перенести сюда):

```
 var params = {
     'host' : 'xxxxx.ru',
     'path' : '/xxx/xxxx.php',
     'method' : 'POST',
     'headers' : {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'  
        }
    };

  https.request(params,function(res){

       });
  https.write(post);
  https.end();
```

Благодарю за ранее!

Answer (score 0):

`cookie` - это заголовок.

фактически, нужно в параметрах прописать еще один заголовок в виде `Cookie: 'key1=value1; key2=value2'` (нужно смотреть документацию для конкретной версии Node)

ну и в ответе проверить заголовки на предмет новых кукисов, которые потом можно записать в файл.

или воспользоваться другой библиотекой, в которой есть поддержка CookieJar из коробки [`npm install request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)